# How to terminate backtracing recursion after first solution is found

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, recursion, n-queens

I am trying to find the first solution of a Backtracking nQueen Algorithm. I want to terminate the execution of the code after I find first solution. But the program keeps running until all the solution is found.

Here's my code:

```
def nQueenBackTrack_first_solution(self, row, n):
      i = 0
      while i < n:
        if self.isTheQueenSafe(row , i):
          self.board[row][i] = "Q"
          if row == n - 1:
            self.print_the_board()
            break
          else:
            self.nQueenBackTrack(row + 1, n)
          self.board[row][i] = "."
        i += 1
```

This keeps printing all the solutions. I need only the first solution. you can also take a look at the other methods used in this program.

```
def isTheQueenSafe(self, row,col):
        for i in range(self.N):
                    # check horizontal Queens
                    if self.does_board_has_a_queen_at(row,i) or self.does_board_has_a_queen_at(i, col):
                        return False
                    # check diagonal Queens
                    s = row + col
                    k = row - col
                    for x in range(self.N):
                        for y in range(self.N):
                            if x + y == s and self.board[x][y] == "Q":
                                return False
                            if x - y == k and self.board[x][y] == "Q":
                                return False        
        return True

def does_board_has_a_queen_at(self,row,col):
    return self.board[row][col] == 'Q'


def print_the_board(self):
    print("solution:")
    for val in self.board:
        print (val, "\n")
```

However the main problem I am facing is that I need to terminate after first solution is executed. Please if someone could help me out with this it would be great.

Comment: Use a global variable and set it to True when you've found the first solution. Or else pass this boolean through all your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to unwind the stack from an arbitrary depth is to use an exception:

**A custom Exception:**

```
class DoneEarly(Exception):
    """An exception to unwind the stack"""
```

**Top level method:**

```
def nQueenBackTrack(self, row, n):
    try:
        self._nQueenBackTrack(row, n)
    except DoneEarly:
        pass
```

**Previous top level method:**

The recursion method is now private, and raises the custom exception when done:

```
def _nQueenBackTrack(self, row, n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        if self.isTheQueenSafe(row, i):
            self.board[row][i] = "Q"
            if row == n - 1:
                self.print_the_board()
                raise DoneEarly
            self._nQueenBackTrack(row + 1, n)
            self.board[row][i] = "."
        i += 1
```

> NOTE: I had no way to test this.